# my requirement is to create a text file and save this to database

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse, ssjs

my requirement is to create a text file from a string and save this to database and sent this text file as attachment via mail.Is it possible. Please help.

The exact need is to create a ics file but first i need to try with a text file.

I don't have any idea about the lotus note application development i have knowledge in angular and react application develoement only

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try it and if you have a specific question ask here for help. StackOverflow is not the place to let others do your work.

Comment: You might want to take this tutorial first: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=F96D8FAF55207C64852575F5007593FB#mobileViewer

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not to create a file. Your requirement is to send out a calendar invitation. Most likely you can just create a Notes document in calendar format and call the `document.send()` method.

Fields needed are described here: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/WPNotesCSSchema/$File/csschema.PDF

You can also create a calendar entry in your mailbox in Notes and use the property dialogue to check it.

Notes will take care of creating the ics attachment  automagically for Internet receipients.